# Как обрабатывать медиагруппу через telegraf.js?

Tags: javascript, telegram, telegraf

У меня есть бот, и в одном из модулей я в сцене создаю объект, в который заносится сообщение пользователя, и который он может потом отредактировать. Сейчас код сцены выглядит так:

```js
getTaskScene.on("message", async (ctx) => {
    let data = {};
    data.text = ctx.message.text ||= "";
    if (ctx.message.photo) {
        data.files = [{ type: "photo", media: `${ctx.message.photo[3].file_id}` }];
        data.type = "photo";
    } else if (ctx.message.document) {
        data.files = ctx.message.document.map((value) => {
            return { type: "document", media: { source: value.file_id } };
        });
        data.type = "document";
    } else {
        data.type = "text";
    }
    ctx.scene.enter("editTaskScene", { data: data });
});
```

Этот код не обрабатывает медиагруппу корректно: если я прикреплю 4 фото, то код отработает 4 раза, а не один.
Есть ли способ обрабатывать медиагруппу как одно сообщение и добавлять все фото сразу же? Я пробовал использовать в главном файле `bot.use(mediaGroup())`, но это, почему-то, не сработало для меня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться событием `"media_group"` вместо `"message"`:

```
bot.on('media_group', async (ctx) => {
  const mediaGroup = ctx.update.message.media_group;

  // Обработка медиагруппы
  // mediaGroup содержит массив объектов с информацией о каждом медиафайле

  // Ваша логика обработки медиагруппы здесь

  // К примеру выводим количество фото в медиагруппе
  const photoCount = mediaGroup.filter((item) => item.type === 'photo').length;
  ctx.reply(`Количество изображений: ${photoCount}`);
});

bot.launch();
```

Comment: Мне нужно что-то дополнительно импортировать? Сейчас я получаю сообщение, что Telegraf.memoryMediaGroup is not a function

Comment: Эту строчку `bot.use(Telegraf.memoryMediaGroup());` нужно убрать, она не нужна в новых версиях

Comment: Даже так, это, почему-то, не работает, но я добавил `import mediaGroup from 'telegraf-media-group';` и `bot.use(mediaGroup())`. В таком случае, событие будет работать нормально.

Comment: С добавлением соответствующих импортов работает?
Обрабатывает медиагруппу как одно сообщение и добавляет все фото сразу же?

Comment: Да, всё так. Если отрабатывает событие media_group, то в ctx появится массив mediaGroup, содержащий сообщения с фотографиями